# ASP.NET Core How to get UserManager working in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to use UserManager in my web app. The app's being built with asp.net core 3.0. 
 I need to get users with a given role(let's say CustomerRole) with own controller.
Normally, I would use this:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Json(new { data = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("CustomerRole").Result });
    }
}
```

And this code returns error 500. UserManager is not initialized either.

I've checked that using code below works as intended. However, I can't get users with a specific role. That's not want I want to achieve.

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Json(new { data = _unitOfWork.Customer.GetAll() });
    }
}
```

Here's *ApplicationUser* code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IApplicationUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

And *ConfigureService*s method from *Startup.cs*:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


    services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

**@Update** 
Solution found.
In `ConfigureServices()` method I fixed the typo, as mvermef instructed. That was big help, really. After that, I changed in *_LoginPartial.cshtml* the following:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

to:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

At this point application was running and I was able to use `UserManager<>` however I wanted. I quickly found out that an user wouldn't be able to register or log in. The soulution was that change(from  to :

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

Remember to make the change in constructors too.
I changed every file in Areas(default name) directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got a typo in your `ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()   //<<<<<< You have IdentityUser
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Because you have `IdentityUser` instead of your derived type it will throw an error... You don't need to use `AddScoped`

Comment: This change caused another expcetion: InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: I got the following exception: System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType

Comment: your UserManager<T> does have dependencies?

Comment: No, it doesn't.